# Windows Phone 8 ApplicationBar

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there really a 4 icon item limit on the applicationbar in windows phone 8?   I tried to create a 5th element and it gave me an error in visual studio 2012 for windows phone that too many items were in the list.

Comment: Yes. Have you ever seen an app with more? That's why they put in the menu below the buttons. Buttons should only be used for the most common tasks associated with the app bar.

Comment: Ok so what controls would be used for navigational purposes?  I am not sure if you are familiar with android and the drawerlayout but I am building an application and trying to design it in windows phone and the 4 limitations are pushing me in different directions from a design layout.   In other device systems I have seen the visible limitation but than a menu option becomes available to click on for options.

Comment: The app bar isn't suited for something like that. It looks fairly simple to implement though if you wanted to create your own. It looks like just a stackpanel that you can hide/show via animations.

Comment: I have seen some other people piggy back of the action bar to make it bindable but nothing that allows extra icons.  I think I might go that route, since I haven't found anything else, to build something at the top for extra navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation :

> An Application Bar contains between one and four buttons, an ellipsis, and a set of text menu items. For more information, see App bar for Windows Phone.

Look at this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar(v=vs.105).aspx

;)

Comment: Yeah it seems you can have n number of textual items but in terms of buttons, there is only allowed up to 4.